# Best way to connect files from assets and Core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm very new to iOS development :)

Right now I'm writing application with cooking recipes. I have model of recipe in Core data. When user pick cooking recipe I want display text with description, image from assets related to that recipe and in UIWebView html file from assets with table with ingredients. How connect core data object with file from assets. In android i would take recipe ID and named files ID.jpg and ID.html, but how do that in iOS with core data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some very good tutorials on the Web.
When I had to for my project, I based my developments on this one : http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated

Edited answer :
You can create a new bundle in the Finder called for example Recipes.bundle (a bundle is a simple folder which name is ended by .bundle) 
In the created bundle, add a new folder for each technical ID with this structure :

```
Recipes.bundle
    |
    - 1
      |- photo.jpg
      |- description.html
    - 2 
      |- photo.jpg
      |- description.html
```

Add the bundle to your Xcode project, and then access the data associated to your record with these lines

```
 NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Recipes" ofType:@"bundle"]; 
 NSString *imageName = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/photo", **technicalID**] ofType:@"jpg"]; 
 UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageName];

 NSString *htmlFilePath = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath] pathForResource:@"description" ofType:@"html"]; 
 NSString *description = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Comment: In this tutorial is description how import existing database, this is not my problem...

Comment: so I need add ID attribute to my recipe entity? :)

Comment: it is the way I did :), since from a Core Data entity, it is not technically possible to access to the value of the Z_PK column.